# Update processing scripts in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-processing, qgis-3

When I edit a processing script (QGIS 3.2) with right click > Edit script... in the processing toolbox, save it and then try to execute it by double clicking it in the processing toolbox, the version that was loaded at QGIS start is executed, not the one just edited. The only (painful!) way to execute my edited script is to restart QGIS 3 any time I made an edit.

Deleting the `__pycache__` folder under `...processing/scripts/` seem to have no effect.

Is there another way to update a script to the edits just made? Like the plugin reloader?

Worth raising an issue?

**UPDATE**
cp. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19934

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's worth raising an issue. A fairly simple workaround is to click the **Options** button in the *Processing Toolbox*:

[image: Options]

Then when the following window shows, just click <kbd>OK</kbd>. This should refresh the path of the scripts (which would be left the same) and reload the scripts:

[image: Options interface]

A wee bit quicker than reloading QGIS :)

Comment: This works sometimes for me, but in most cases QGIS crashes when trying this (cp. https://issues.qgis.org/issues/19934), which obviously has the advantage of not having to restart QGIS manually, but simply using the 'restart QGIS' button...

Comment: @JochenSchwarze - Ahh, hasn't crashed for me so far. Hopefully this issue will get resolved soon :)

Comment: this did not work for me unfortunately. I have various scripts importing each other, maybe that's why?